# Angular 9, take up full width in component

Tags: angular, formatting

I am having trouble getting the content in one of my angular template files to take up the full width and height of the page. Basicaly I am getting the following:
[image]

But I would like something like this:
[image]
I have tried putting my main div in the template.html as width: 100%; but I am not getting any difference. Perhaps this has something to do with the styling of other components. I am not sure how to solve this, any help would be appreicated!

Here is an screenshot of the display and here is the html, css for the navbar and content.

**header.html**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand">Brand</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li routerLinkActive="active"><a routerLink="/link1" id="identified">Link 1</a></li>
        <li routerLinkActive="active"><a routerLink="/link2" id="identified">Link 2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

**header.css**

```
.navbar-default {
  background-color: #7cd8fc;
}

.navbar-brand {
  color: white;
}
.navbar-brand:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: #777799;
}
.navbar-brand:active {
  color: white;
}
#identified {
  color: black;
}
#identified:hover {
  background-color: #cadbda;
  /* background-color: #777799; */
}

* {
  font-family: Cambria; 
}
```

**Content.html**

```
<div class="container" style="width:100%;">
  text<br>
  text<br>
  text<br>
  text<br>
  text<br>
  text<br>
  text<br>
  text<br>
  text<br>
  text<br>
  text<br>
  text<br>
  text<br>
  text<br>
  text<br>
  text<br>
  text<br>
</div>
```

**Content.css**

```
(empty)
```

**app.component.html**

```
<app-header></app-header>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-12">
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

**app.component.css**

```
(empty)
```

**Offending Display:**

[image]

Comment: please add your html and css code

Comment: I have added the relevant code, maybe it's the divs in my app.component.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change

```html
<div class="container">
```

to

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
```

bootstraps container class has left and right margins. use the fluid container to create a container without that margins.

for reference https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/overview/#containers

Comment: Yes, i have edited this and it works! Thanks for your help